why bending moment diagram not return to 0?
I worry my diagram bending moment or Shear Force Diagram I have drawn is wrong

So I have problem like the picture no.1 show and have solved then get reaction support (Ray & Rby) on The picture no.2 is my calculation

The question is why my line for bending moment not return to 0 or closed to straight line ?

You can use linear superposition, so your FBD is the sum of the FBD for each of the  three loads. This is a good way of error proofing your FBD

Well, Thanks for suggestion .

It's look like my diagram is wrong

except my calculation

It does not matter. Let's check, RA4000 + 1001000 - 354000 - 50500 = 0; RA = 16.25.

what?! are you sure mm to meter is equal 1*1000?

and the value moment is just 100 then do not multiply with distance

I think you did something wrong in getting support reactions:
$\sum M_B$ = 0
Assuming $R_A$ is pointing upward, and clockwise rotation is positive:
$R_A * 4 + 100 - 35*2*2 - 50*0.5 = 0$
$R_A = 16.25$
$R_B = 35*2 + 50 - R_A = 103.75$
Now the moment shall return to zero on both ends.

wait a minute , the distance is using milimeters not meters . so , I am not wrong

But it should be meter that's why , one of distance for load or total distance multiplly 10^-3 meter

Am i right ? or Do I wrong ?@r13

It does not matter. RA4000 + 1001000 - 354000 - 50500 = 0, what is RA then?

what?! are you sure mm to meter is equal 1*1000? @r13

and the value moment is just 100 then do not multiply with distance

@Arton Read the unit of the given moment and make a unit conversion - 100 kN-m = ? kN-mm.

okay, you win .you're right . Thank youu so much

OHH YESS, YOU'RE RIGHT IT DOESN'T MATTER

@r13 answer is correct. As long as we use consistent units, it doesn't matter.
